# Find words in a string

Tags: python

I want to search for words in a string.
Ex: Vet approved home made dog food.
If I'm searching for dog food as these two words are present in the above sentence it should return me that sentence.
If possible I want the code in python.

I tried str.contains('dog|food') but didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I 100% understand what you're trying in a full context but the code below gives the intended results for the example you gave, it returns `True` if any of the words in the `words list` are matched with any of the words in the `string`. Then simply print out the string if result of `all` is `True`.

```
string = 'Vet approved home made dog food'
words = ['dog', 'food']
res = all(word in string for word in words)
if res:
    print(string)
else:
    print('Words not found in string.')
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question both words should appear in the sentence, so we would have to change `any` to `all`.

Comment: you're right, I adjusted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the string and see if the word you want is present.
In python, while handling with strings, you can use the `find()` function.
This will give the index of the first occurance of the word.

```
str="Vet approved home made dog food. If I'm searching for dog food"
print(str.find("food"))
```

This will return the first occurance.

A way more better way to approach would be using regular expressions.
You would have to import re module.
THe syntax is `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`

You can later use the group() function and then find out the occurances.
import re

```
# Target String
target_string = "et approved home made dog food"

# find substring 'dog food'
result = re.search(r"dog food", target_string)

# Print matching substring
print(result.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.contains()` method is not a valid python method.

The *python way* of checking containment would be the `in` keyword.

```py
sentence = 'Vet approved home made dog food'
word = 'dog'

found = word in sentence

# Prints 'True'
print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient but here we go:

```
l = []
x= string.split(" ")
for i in range(len(x - 1):
     combination = x[i] + ' ' + x[i+1]
     l.append(combination)
if "dog food" in l:
     return True
else:
    return False
```

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).